# How to update mock values state in Jest React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-typescript

I need guidance on how to test and change react context mock values with jest,
What I have done is created context which has two properties inputs and setInputs
with my test the initial test are passing with the mock state of the  inputs, where I hit a wall is how to change the values of the valuesValidate objects from property valid from mock state false to become true and test that there is change. I am just starting whit jest tesing so I would Appreciate any comments and help. I want to simulate a typing event that will change the values in the mocked stated for the valiedated properties to become from false to true.
This is my test

```
  it("user types on input fields", () => {
    const mockState = {
      initial: {
        email: "some@email.com",
        password: "1234567asd",
        secretQuestionA: "some question",
        secretQuestionB: "some question",
      },
      valuesValidate: {
        email: { valid: false, errorMessage: "" },
        password: { valid: false, errorMessage: "" },
        secretQuestionA: { valid: false, errorMessage: "" },
        secretQuestionB: { valid: false, errorMessage: "" },
      },
    };

    const setInputs = jest.fn();
    const inputs: InputsInitiaState = mockState;
    const storeValues: IAccountDetailsContextProps = {
      inputs,
      setInputs,
    };

    render(
      <AccountDetalsContext.Provider value={storeValues}>
        <AccountDetails />
      </AccountDetalsContext.Provider>
    );
    const emailInput = screen.getByTestId("email");
    const passwordInput = screen.getByTestId("password");
    const securityQuestionAInput = screen.getByTestId("security-question-1");
    const securityQuestionBInput = screen.getByTestId("security-question-2");

    const button = screen.getByTestId("continue-button");

    user.click(button);

    expect(emailInput).toHaveValue("some@email.com");
    expect(passwordInput).toHaveValue("1234567asd");
    expect(securityQuestionAInput).toHaveValue("some question");
    expect(securityQuestionBInput).toHaveValue("some question");
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();

  });
```

Comment: Any solution? I have a similar issue. Also, where did you get AccountDetailsContext.Provider?

Comment: How did your context value be changed in the real implementation of your code?